# Controlling events of a Twilio call

Tags: java, twilio

In the next sample code, Twilio puts in conversation OPERATOR_PHONE_NUMBER to CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER, and records the call.

But I don't know what should be the code to control some things, one or both of the phones...:

1. does not exist.
2. exists but communicates.
3. exists, does not communicate but does not pick up.
4. exists, does not communicate, picks up and the conversation takes place.

   ```
   import com.twilio.Twilio;
   import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
   import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.CallCreator;
   import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
   import com.twilio.type.Twiml;

   public class SimpleCallWithRecording2 {
   private static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
   private static final String AUTH_TOKEN  = "9ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

   private static final String ASSIGNED_PHONE_NUMBER = "+15999999999999";  

   //Must be verified numbers in trial account
   private static final String OPERATOR_PHONE_NUMBER = "+34888888888";
   private static final String CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER   = "+34777777777";


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
       Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

       PhoneNumber to = new PhoneNumber(OPERATOR_PHONE_NUMBER);

       PhoneNumber from = new PhoneNumber(ASSIGNED_PHONE_NUMBER);

       Twiml twiml = new Twiml(
           "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>                    " +  
           "<Response>                                                    " +
           "   <Say voice=\"woman\">This is said by a robotic woman</Say> " +          
           "   <Dial>                                                     " +
           "      <Number> " + CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER + "</Number>           " +
           "   </Dial>                                                    " +
           "</Response>                                                   " );

       CallCreator callCreator = Call.creator(to, from, twiml);
           callCreator.setRecord(true);

       Call call = callCreator.create();
       System.out.println(call);
   }
   ```

   }

In the doc I see something could be done with `callCreator.setStatusCallback(URI.create("https://www.myapp.com/events"))`, and some clasification of events: "**initiated**", "**ringing**", "**answered**", "**completed**". BUT I havent find the code "on the other side", I mean in https://www.myapp.com/events extreme ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a that rest endpoint and set it as status callback url. 
The url will recieve events from twilio.

Refer [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallback)

**edit**: if you also need events from the nested  verb, define attribute 'action' to it.

ie

```
 <Dial action="//callbackURL">
 <Number>   CLIENT_PHONE_NUMBER  </Number> 
 </Dial>
```

that way you'll know your cases 1 ,2 ,3 ,4.

and to "control" the call, you just respond with the desired TwiML to the  callback request. Hope this clarifies.

**edit2**: You need to do something like:

```
//handles callback url
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
{  //...
   TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
   String callSid = request.getParameter("CallSid");
   //handle call specific data
   switch(request.getParameter("CallStatus")){
      case "no-answer": //construct twiML
      case "ringing" ://...
    }
    //...
   response.setContentType("application/xml");
   response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXML());
}
```

See: [IVR - Example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/ivr-phone-tree-java-servlets)

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but, do you know a complete/concrete example that shows how to assign "initiated" event to some REST URL, "ringing" event to some different REST URL, and so on?

Comment: you cannot assign different urls to different events initially, 
you can however differentiate the events using the 'CallStatus' param in the callback request.
See https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallback

Comment: In case I use callCreator.setStatusCallbackMethod(HttpMethod.POST); what object can I get in the Rest webservice, Call instance or CallCreator instance? (In the Twilio doc I havent find a WebService example that read the status of the call an do whatever needed)

Comment: I dont think there are wrappers for callback requests, so will not get any objects, you will only receive raw HTTP requests, which you can respond with a new twiML which will control further call flow

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Ra Ja, in your 'edit2', is necesary to return a TwiMLResponse?